# Rails 5 accessing multiple database attributes at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the folowing problem:

My Database schema looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180115094430) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "remember_digest"
    t.boolean "admin"
    t.string "activation_digest"
    t.boolean "activated"
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.float "zero_till_one"
    t.float "one_till_two"
    t.float "two_till_three"
    t.float "three_till_four"
    t.float "four_till_five"
    t.float "five_till_six"
    t.float "six_till_seven"
    t.float "seven_till_eight"
    t.float "eight_till_nine"
    t.float "nine_till_ten"
    t.float "ten_till_eleven"
    t.float "eleven_till_twelve"
    t.float "twelve_till_thirteen"
    t.float "thirteen_till_fourteen"
    t.float "fourteen_till_fifteen"
    t.float "fifteen_till_sixteen"
    t.float "sixteen_till_seventeen"
    t.float "seventeen_till_eightteen"
    t.float "eightteen_till_nineteen"
    t.float "nineteen_till_twenty"
    t.float "twenty_till_twentyone"
    t.float "twentyone_till_twentytwo"
    t.float "twentytwo_till_twentythree"
    t.float "twentythree_till_zero"
  end

end
```

When working with the database I want to access the `zero_till one` till `twentythree_till_zero` attributes/columns and assign them together with their values to a hash. I know I can access every single value with `@user.zero_till_one` and so on but isn't there a way to index the columns and loop over the indices to save them in a hash or something similar like that.

Sorry for asking I am very new to RoR and the app I am programming is the first app after the Michael Hartl tutorial.

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: didn't get properly, could you show some examples what do you exactly want?

Comment: Have you tried select query? it can be something like `User.select(: zero_till_one, : one_till_two, : two_till_three).where(id: xx).as_josn` solving it through query would be much faster

Comment: I want the 24 t.float colums as a hash for the current user.  Accessing them with `user.zero_till_one` gives me only one value and I don't want to do this 24 times.

Comment: @SebastianPeter could you check the answer given below and let me know if its helpful for you, i have given answer as i understood your requirement. hope it will help you,

Comment: I am quite curious about why you need this kind of schema, what do you need to store there?

Comment: @xlembouras I am still tripping after looking at the schema :) . no intentions to offend the OP.

Comment: @Abhinay seems like a denormalization attempt for aggregating timestamped data.

Comment: I think storing entire data straight into a `json` type column would be more helpful. @xlembouras

Comment: @xlembouras, no Offense taken. My daughter has diabetes type one. I am programming a diabetes diary app. At the frontend, when I type in the eaten carbohydrates at a given time rails should provide the so called BU-factor(Bread Unit Factor, Indicates how much insulin is needed for 10g of carbohydrates). according to the hour. This factor is different for every person and hence is saved for every person in the database. It differs from hour to hour and from user to user.  afriend told me that i cannot name a column "1h-2h" so I did it the way I did. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sebastian, you made my day already. hats off to you man. i think whatever you are doing is great and you should forget about the best approach right now. sorry for all the non-sense i spoke about the schema etc. Kudos to you!!

Comment: @SebastianPeter that is inspiring! If it works then its ok :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not understanding it wrong then, you want hash from user object. You can use `user.serializable_hash` to convert user object to hash or please explain further your requirement.

Comment: Thank You. Exactly I want the user object as a hash but only the 24 float keys/values. Not the name email digests etc..

Comment: how are you getting user object?

Comment: Yeah thats it. Serializable_hash also has an except option so thats the thing I was looking for.

Comment: @SebastianPeter you can solve this in the hash's scope by using [Hash#keep_if](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/keep_if)
`hash.keep_if {|k,_| k[/^zero_till/] }`

Answer (score 2):

```
user.serializable_hash.except('name','email')
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can use `attributes` method from active record.

```
user.attributes.except('name', 'email')
```

I think this is a cleaner approach.